# Route NetBIOS protocol through internet

Tags: networking, router, lan, netbios

I have LAN witch connected to Internet through ADSL router and I have run file sharing in the LAN.

I want to access my file sharing by another location in the Internet and i know this is not the way to connect file sharing through internet and i can use FTP or remote desktop to inside LAN computer and i know it is not safe to share files in the web but my questions are :

1- Is there any way i can use feature like port forwarding through router to connect individual computer in the LAN ?

2- How can i access that Sharing with a program from outside the LAN ?

3- Does NetBIOS protocol work through internet ?

- lets say i cant use another way or change anything except port forwarding on the router , can i able to access my shared files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets answer your questions in reverse:

1. NetBIOS itself is not a routable protocol, so in its native
   state, no it cannot travel the internet. using NetBIOS over TCP/IP,
   you can route it however.
2. a client like sambaclient (linux) is
   required to access the share. most windows and linux distros have
   the client built in.
3. yes, you can forward tcp/137-139 and UDP/445
   (and udp/389 if you are using active directory)

all that said, this is a really really really bad idea. make sure you lock down all the administrative shares, as many clients ignore teh $ rule for hidden shares, and if an attacker gets access to IPC$ or ADMIN$, you are toast.

Comment: NetBIOS itself is just an API, not a real protocol. It's unroutable when run over NBF, but routable over IPX or TCP/IP (NBT).

Answer (score 1):

NetBIOS-over-TCP/IP can work over the Internet – *mostly: see the part about NBNS below.*

**For file sharing, Windows uses the SMB protocol.**

- Modern versions of Windows use SMB directly over TCP over **TCP port 445**.
- Traditionally, SMB was used over NetBIOS Session Service. These days NetBIOS runs over TCP/IP (aka NetBT) and works over the Internet, using **TCP port 139**.
- For Windows to work properly, **ICMP Ping should be allowed** as well.
- Note that you **cannot change the ports** when connecting from other Windows computers; you must use ports 445 and 139. This means that you can only access *one computer* over the Internet directly.

What *does not work* is the NetBIOS Name Service, which relies on broadcasts – UDP port 137 when using TCP/IP, for example. Even if you forwarded this in your router, it still wouldn't work. **However, the Name Service is *not needed* for file sharing to work.** You can use DNS in its place, or just enter the IP address directly: e.g. `\\192.0.2.1\public-files`.

**Keep in mind that exposing SMB and/or NetBIOS to the Internet can be horribly insecure.** There is no data encryption at all, the authentication protocol is weak against sniffers, and the Windows SMB/NetBIOS implementation has had **many** security holes in the past. **Avoid doing this – set up a VPN instead.**